pytest - Mockear query SQLAlchemy
Estoy intentando pasar tests a los métodos por los cuales obtengo los datos de la base de datos, y los devuelve a través de un mapper, he conseguido mockear la llamada entera a un método, pero no una linea concreta de un método.
Este es el metodo:
class MiClase2:
    def find_by_id(self, id_: int) -> MiClase:
        mi_objeto = self.session.query(MiClase).get(id_)
        if mi_objeto:
            return self.mapper.from_model(mi_objeto)

        raise ObjectNotFoundException(id_)

Me gustaría mockear el resultado de la linea: self.session.query(MiClase).get(id_).
He probado con:
session_mock = mocker.MagicMock(spec=Session)

mi_clase2 = MiClase2(session_mock)

y
mocker.patch.object(mi_clase2, 'find_by_id.self.session.query.get').return_value = mocked_value
Pero ninguna me funcina.
Gracias de antemano
